# Inner-classes vs. nested types

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

Consider this question:

*[Do `const T` and `T` have no difference when taking its nested type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61430178)*

It has been tagged with [inner-classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inner-classes), but it's only about non-class types defined within a class. Is there / should there be another tag for such types? If not, shouldn't we have a synonym [nested-class-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nested-class-types) for `[tag:inner-classes]` or perhaps the other way around?

Comment: so i at least understand so at a very basic level what you are talking about, but believe or not, there are people that can't understand at all what it is about . Why do you not explain it in much much broader words, for every one to understand.

Comment: Why not simply using none? Not every topic deserves a standalone tag, specially if another already covers the topic of the question.

Comment: @Braiam: Well, the reason is that I see an invalid use of [tag:inner-classes] - so it's one of: untagging, adding a synonym, or adding a new tag.

Comment: @nbk: Not sure what I can explain better, but I've edited to try.

Comment: the tag is already deleted and i think we should have a new tag nested-data-types

Comment: @nbk: Then perhaps make that an answer? Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Using neither is a valid option in this case. Inner classes, nested class types, etc. are minutiae of language specifications, and as such the language tag already covers topics about these. Such a narrow tag doesn't offer any *ad valorem* to the question, the asker or the answerers.